# Write a function given a zero-indexed matrix A consisting of N rows and M columns of integers, returns the number of equilibrium points of matrix A

Tags: python, matrix

Hey guys I am doing a question where I have to find a point in a Matrix A of N x M rows such that

the sum of rows above the point is equal to the sum of row

Consider this example

```
/**
 * A[0][0] = 2    A[0][1] = 7    A[0][2] =  5
 * A[1][0] = 3    A[1][1] = 1    A[1][2] =  1
 * A[2][0] = 2    A[2][1] = 1    A[2][2] = -7
 * A[3][0] = 0    A[3][1] = 2    A[3][2] =  1
 * A[4][0] = 1    A[4][1] = 6    A[4][2] =  8
 * @param matrix
 * @return
 */
```

In this example the if we look at the point A[1][1], it can be said that the row above (sum = 14) is equal to the sum of rows below the point. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You should at least try to write some code to solve your problem and if it doesn’t work edit it into the question.

Comment: So, since you are only looking at rows, there are three equilibrium points?

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Equilibrium {

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Equilibrium.class);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] A = new int[][] { 
        { 2, 7, 5 }, 
        { 3, 1, 1 }, 
        { 2, 1, -7 },
        { 0, 2, 1 }, 
        { 1, 6, 8 } };
}

private static int solution(int[][] A) {
    
    int[] row = new int[A.length];
    int[] column = new int[A[0].length];
    int equiRow = 0;
    int equiColumn = 0;

    int position = 0;
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column.length; j++) {
            num += A[i][j];
        }
        row[position++] = num;
        num = 0;
    }
    position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            num += A[j][i];
        }
        column[position++] = num;
        num = 0;
    }       
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        int leftsum = 0; 
        int rightsum = 0; /
        
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
            leftsum += row[j];
        }
        
        for (int k = i + 1; k < row.length; k++) { 
            rightsum += row[k];
        }
        
        
        if (leftsum == rightsum) {
            equiRow++;              
        }
    }
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
        int leftsum = 0; 
        int rightsum = 0; 
        
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
            leftsum += column[j];
        }
        
        for (int k = i + 1; k < column.length; k++) { 
            rightsum += column[k];
        }
        
        
        if (leftsum == rightsum) {
            equiColumn++;               
        }
    }
    return equiRow * equiColumn;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
// C++ Solution
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int solution(vector<vector<int>> &A) {
    int p= A.size(), q= A[0].size();
    vector<long> rowPreSum(p), colPreSum(q);
    int i, j;
    for (i= 0; i < p; i++) {
        rowPreSum[i]= (i > 0)? rowPreSum[i-1] : 0;
        for (j= 0; j < q; j++)
            rowPreSum[i]+= A[i][j];
    }
    for (i= 0; i < q; i++) {
        colPreSum[i]= (i > 0)? colPreSum[i-1] : 0;
        for (j= 0; j < p; j++)
            colPreSum[i]+= A[j][i];
    }
    int rowEqCount= 0, colEqCount= 0;
    for (i= 0; i < p; i++)
        if (rowPreSum[p-1] - rowPreSum[i] == ((i > 0)? rowPreSum[i-1] : 0))
            rowEqCount++;
    for (i= 0; i < q; i++)
        if (colPreSum[q-1] - colPreSum[i] == ((i > 0)? colPreSum[i-1] : 0))
            colEqCount++;
    return (rowEqCount*colEqCount);
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> A{  { 2, 7, 5 }, 
                            { 3, 1, 1 }, 
                            { 2, 1, -7 },
                            { 0, 2, 1 }, 
                            { 1, 6, 8 }  };
    
    cout<< solution(A);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is about [`Python`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info), so why did you answered it with [`Cpp`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info)?